# how to access the same instance of a class in django view from 2 different ajax requests

Tags: python, ajax, django, class

Ok so i'm using django to generate my webpage and i have some views which are accessable via ajax. The issue i'm having is that i want to call one of the views which creates an object instance, then i want to call a second view but i want the second view to use the object instance of the first view.

Example:

```
    def view1(request):
        x = MyClass()

    def view2(request):
        y = x.some_method()
        return JsonResponse(y)
```

Do i need to move to a class based view? or is there a way to do the above?
Many thanks in advance :D

Comment: No. There is **no way** to do this. Store the information you need to recreate the instance in the database or the session, and recreate it in the second view.

Answer (score 0):

The object instance i wanted to maintain was a selenium webdriver instance and as such can't be serialized and stored in a database. The only workaround i have found is to use a global variable dictionary where the key is the csrf or session token and the value to the webdriver object instance.